# How can I remove element from UI Flutter

Tags: flutter, video

[image]

I am using image picker to pick video and then it displays on my UI so I want to remove picked video thumbnail from my screen, on picked video there is red  button, when user clicks on this button video should be removed from screen. I have tried but it seems i am doing something wrong with function I think, here is my code

```
 if (_image != null)
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
        Container(
        height: 55,
        width: 60,
          child: Image.memory(_image)),
          Positioned(
          top: -15,
          right: -15,
          child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.circular(
          16.0),
          child: IconButton(
          hoverColor: Colors.red,
          icon: Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.red,
          size: 23,
           ),
          onPressed: () =>
             _removeVideo),
           ),
         ),
        ],
        ),

 Future<void> _videoPicker() async {
    if (mounted) {
      final file = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (file?.path != null) {
        final thumbnail = await _flutterVideoCompress.getThumbnail(
          file.path,
          quality: 50,
          position: -1,
        );

        setState(() {
          _image = thumbnail;
        });

        final resultFile = await _flutterVideoCompress.getThumbnailWithFile(
          file.path,
          quality: 50,
          position: -1,
        );
        debugPrint(resultFile.path);

        assert(resultFile.existsSync());

        debugPrint('file Exists: ${resultFile.existsSync()}');

        final MediaInfo info = await _flutterVideoCompress.compressVideo(
          file.path,
          deleteOrigin: false,
          quality: VideoQuality.LowQuality,
        );
        debugPrint(info.toJson().toString());
      }
    }
  }



 void _removeVideo() {
    setState(() {
      _image = null;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try the `Visibility` widget. Since, I don't understand what you are trying to do, I wouldn't be able to help you out with the implementation of the widget. I explained how to use it here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60798709/easy-way-to-hide-a-widget-after-some-duration-in-flutter/60798850#60798850

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to hide a widget, I want to remove it completely. Which part you don't understand? There is a video on screen which is picked with image_picker, so I put this video in container and on this container i put button. When user click on this button picked video should be removed from the screen. This what i want

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think it is possible to do that programmatically. The only way to do that is to hide it and set it to gone so it appears off screen using the Visibility widget. Another way is to put the videos in a ListView.builder and then remove the item from ListView.builder. You can store the items to local storage using sqflite or fetch them from the web through json.

Comment: How can I put videos in ListView.builder with the code above ?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials online. You just need to Google. Here are some of them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdWhYERuv7g and https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb

Answer (score 0):

get rid of if (_image != null), try following instead

```
_image == null ? Container(): Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
    Container(
    height: 55,
    width: 60,
      child: Image.memory(_image)),
      Positioned(
      top: -15,
      right: -15,
      child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius:
      BorderRadius.circular(
      16.0),
      child: IconButton(
      hoverColor: Colors.red,
      icon: Icon(
      Icons.delete,
      color: Colors.red,
      size: 23,
       ),
      onPressed: () =>
         _removeVideo),
       ),
     ),
    ],
    ),
```